# Question about Inversion of Partial Derivatives

Tags: calculus, notation, partial-derivative

If I want to calculate $ \frac{\partial x }{\partial u}$ and $ \frac{\partial x }{\partial v}$ where $$u = \frac{y}{x^3}, v = \frac{x}{y^3}$$ could I calculate $ \frac{\partial u }{\partial x}$ and $ \frac{\partial v }{\partial x}$ then take the reciprocal? I have proceeded as if I can not and it is very challenging.

Comment: Please consider producing a more objective and informative title.

Comment: Would you happen to know the answer to my question?

Answer (score 3):

In general, no. However, you can compute the Jacobian and invert that (when it's nonsingular, of course) to get the partial derivatives of the inverse map.