# $x =r\cos \theta$ and $y = r\sin\theta$, determine $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> Given that $x =r\cos \theta$ and $y = r\sin\theta$, determine $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}$

**Attempt:**

I thought I'd calculate $\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}$, treat it as a fraction and say $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x} = 1/\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}$, however that doesn't work.

Then I thought I'd set $r = \frac{x}{\cos \theta}$ and differentiate about $x$, but this path leads to the same result above.

I'm not sure how $y = r\sin \theta$ comes into play here.

**Official Answer:**

$$ \frac{\partial r}{\partial x} = \cos \theta, \quad \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x} = \frac{- \sin\theta }{r}$$

Comment: No, that doesn’t work (and hardly ever does for partial derivatives). See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1588175/265466), among others. [This one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1588175/265466) is virtually a duplicate of yours, as one of the answers covers the derivatives you’re trying to compute, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Observe that $r^2=x^2+y^2$, so 
$$2r\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}=2x \implies \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}=\frac{x}{r}=\cos\theta$$
Similarly you can use $\tan \theta=\frac{y}{x}$ for the other partial derivative.