# $x=r\cos \theta$ and $y=r\sin \theta$ determine partial derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

My question is the same as this one: [$x =r\cos \theta$ and $y = r\sin\theta$, determine $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3365820/x-r-cos-theta-and-y-r-sin-theta-determine-frac-partial-r-partial-x?rq=1)

except that I do not know how to prove that $$ \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}=-\frac{\sin \theta}{r} $$ using the fact that $\tan \theta=\frac{y}{x}$.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to derive $\theta=\tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})$ but this is getting to complicated, I do not know where to go, I also made a scheme because but otherwise I do not have any other idea on where to go.

Comment: wait my idea was great I just found the result nevermind, but maybe someone as an other idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evaluate partial derivative of $\tan\theta$ with respect to $x$.

$$\sec^2\theta \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x} = -\frac{y}{x^2}$$
After rearranging
$$ \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x} = -\frac{y\cos^2\theta}{x^2}$$
you can write $\cos\theta = \frac{x}{r}$
$$ \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x} = -\frac{y\ x^2}{r^2\ x^2}$$
write $y = r\sin\theta$
$$\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x} = -\frac{\sin\theta}{r}$$

Comment: Even simpler thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Use Jacobian Matrix Inversion.

$\qquad\begin{align}\dfrac{\partial\begin{bmatrix}r&\theta\end{bmatrix}}{\partial\begin{bmatrix}x&y\end{bmatrix}}&=\left(\dfrac{\partial\begin{bmatrix}x&y\end{bmatrix}}{\partial\begin{bmatrix}r&\theta\end{bmatrix}}\right)^{-1}\\[1ex]&=\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\partial~r \cos\theta}{\partial r}&\dfrac{\partial~r \cos\theta}{\partial \theta}\\\dfrac{\partial~r \sin\theta}{\partial r}&\dfrac{\partial~r \sin\theta}{\partial \theta}\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\\[1ex]&=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&- r\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&r\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{1}{r}\begin{bmatrix}r\cos\theta&r\sin\theta\\-\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}\\[1ex]&=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&\sin\theta\\ -r^{-1}\sin\theta&r^{-1}\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}\end{align}$

---

So $\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x}=\cos\theta~$, $\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial y}=\sin\theta~$, $\dfrac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}=\dfrac{-\sin\theta}{r}~$, and $\dfrac{\partial\theta}{\partial y}=\dfrac{\cos\theta}{r}~$.